# Custom numeric format automatics make the last 2 digit into decimal point

Tags: c#, .net

How can i make the last two digit into decimal point?

Example simulation would be
Test: 2
Result: 0.02

Test: 24
Result: 0.24

Test: 287567
Result: 2875.67

Can i achieve this with string.format? 
Thanks

Comment: Please show us your effort. What have you already tried? What are _specific_ issues you encounter while trying to solve your task? Please read our [ask] topics.

Comment: Divide by 100 yourself, then use String.Format(if needed at all)

Answer (score 3):

Seem to me that you're actually dividing by 100, so that's what you can do:

```
int number = 2;
decimal newNumber = (decimal)number / 100;
string text = newNumber.ToString("F2");
```

Now `text` will contain "`0.02`" - always with 2 digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .ToString() formatting to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
1234.ToString("0'.'##");
//Outputs: 12.34
```